# Validate multiple content-types with Paperclip and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I'm using the Paperclip gem for Rails in order to allow users to upload a photo of themselves. I obviously only want to accept `jpeg`, `gif` or `png` images. What is the proper way to validate these files were uploaded instead of something else like a word document?

According to [the Paperclip docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations), I validate content-type with:

```
validates_attachment :document, content_type: "application/pdf"
```

What is the proper way to validate the above different image formats (`gif`, `png`, `jpeg`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class Doc
  has_attached_file :document
  validates_attachment_content_type :document, 
                                    :content_type => /^document\/(png|gif|jpeg)/,
                                    :message => 'only (png/gif/jpeg) images'
end
```

Comment: there is a typo. `validates_attachment_content_type :image,` should be `validates_attachment_content_type :document`